# Как найти ядро произвольного полигона

Tags: python, алгоритм, геометрия

Подскажите, есть массив точек, по которым построен полигон. Какие библиотеки можно использовать, чтобы найти ядро полигона?

Comment: А что есть ядро в вашем понимании

Comment: Центр? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: Ядро полигона - множество точек, из которых обозрима вся внутренность полигона. Ядром обладают только звездчатые полигоны (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon). См. также Задачу о Картинной Галерее (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5)

Comment: Ну тогда просто: пересечение полуплоскостей, содержащих стороны.

Comment: @VladD, именно приведенное AnT определение ядра я и хочу найти. Можно ли поподробнее (если не трудно в привязке к Python) рассказать о реализации алгоритма пересечения плоскостей?

Comment: Ну смотрите. Пересечение полуплоскостей есть выпуклая фигура, ограниченная либо многоугольником, либо «разомкнутым» в бесконечность многоугольником (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5ggl.png), либо вырожденным в отрезок, точку или пустое множество случаем. Вам нужно поддерживать упорядоченный список вершин, и уметь добавить ещё одну полуплоскость (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEDVx.png), вот собственно и всё.